# Proof by induction $\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k=-n$

Tags: induction

Hi I am trying to proof that
$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k=-n$ by induction.

I end up here:
$-n+(-1)^{2n+2-1} \cdot (2n+2) = -n -2n -2 \ne -n$

Could someone help me find my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: What matters is *how* did you end up there?

Comment: When we increment from $n=m$ to $n=m+1$ we add **two** terms,$$\sum_{k=2m+1}^{2m+2}(-1)^{k-1}k=(2m+1)-(2m+2)=-1.$$You seem to have only included the $k=2m+2$ term.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, I have overlooked that I needed to add the **two** last terms of the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $n=1$,
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=1}^{2}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k=(-1)^1\cdot1=-1.
\end{equation*}
Suppose it holds for $n$, *i. e.*,
\begin{equation}\label{1}
\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k=-n.  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)
\end{equation}
Let's prove the result for $n+1$,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k & = \sum_{k=1}^{2n+2}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k \ \ \ \ \  \text{(we separate the last two terms of the sum)}\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k-1}\cdot k+(-1)^{(2n+1)-1}\cdot(2n+1)+(-1)^{(2n+2)-1}\cdot(2n+2)\\
& =\underbrace{-n}_{\text{For} (1)}+(-1)^{2n}\cdot(2n+1)+(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot(2n+2)\\
& =-n+2n+1+(-1)(2n+2)\\
&=-n+2n+1-2n-2=-n-1\\
&=-(n+1).
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Plug in $n=1$ and see that the sum is $ -1 $.
Now, assume the property holds for some $n$. From this one is to show that it implies that the property holds for $n+1$. Notice that if $n=1$, the formula must hold for $n=2$. But since it holds for $n=2$, it must also be true for $n=3$, and so on. Hence the name: induction.

Proof that if $\sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}k = -n$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)} (-1)^{k-1}k$:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{2(n+1)} (-1)^{k-1}k = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} (-1)^{k-1}k + (2n+1) - (2n-2) = -n + 2n + 1 - 2n - 2 = -n - 1 = -(n+1). $$ This is because of the induction hypothesis. Therefore the property holds for all positive integers $n$.